# Git/etckeeper shared between systems

Tags: arch-linux, raspberry-pi, etc

I've four Raspberry PiZeroW on my system running [ArchLinux ARM (alarm)](https://archlinuxarm.org/) that I use solely as [snapclient](https://github.com/badaix/snapcast) for streaming music synchronously about the house.

Initially I had one PiZeroW and I used [etckeeper](https://etckeeper.branchable.com) to track and back up the config to a private repo on [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com) and all was simple.  This is `alarmpi3` (as I've two more PiZero2 B+'s which are `alarmpi` and `alarmpi2`).

To add PiZeroW's to the system I simply use `dd` to copy the system between microSD from `alarmpi3` to `alarmpi4`, `alarmpi5` and `alarmpi6`.  I then edit `/etc/hostname` and change the `Port` entry in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` so each is using a unique port.

When I added `alarmpi4` I also modified `/etc/.git/config` so it used its own repo and was perfectly happy updating the systems concurrently, I never have any real need to tweak configuration files beyond those that are modified when I update.

Today I added `alarmpi5` and `alarmpi6` (both PiZeroW) and am wondering if I can use a single repo of `etckeeper` across all machines?

I would have to exclude the files that differ, i.e.

```
/etc/hostname
/etc/sshd/sshd_config
```

..although I could happily have them all running `sshd` on the same port.

In writing this I'm now wondering whether I even need to bother with backing up `/etc/` for `alarmpi4`, `alarmpi5` and `alarmpi6`.  They are just clones of `alarmpi3` and as long as I keep `alarmpi3` backed up its simple to replace the system on any of the later (e.g. microSD card failure) by simply using `dd` to clone the drives again.

Any thoughts, suggestions or recommendations would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I've opted to simplify my life and since `alarmpi4`, `alarmpi5` and `alarmpi6` are in essence clones of `alarmpi3` (with `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/sshd/sshd_config` modified) I am only backing up `/etc` on `alarmpi3`.